# Removing Duplicate Values not working - expected bool?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, data-analysis

My data set looks something like

[image]

I am trying 2 functions to clean up the df - to first remove all equal combos in the df - meaning if the same ids are combo together like row 1 and row 3 it removes that but then when I try the second function that then removes any duplicate in each column - it runs with no error but the actual duplicates are not being removed?

```
def remove_dup_combos(df):
u = df.filter(like='id').values
m = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(u, axis=1)).duplicated()
df = df[~m]

return df



def remove_dups(df):
   df = df = df.drop_duplicates(['id1', 'id2'])

  return df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need if need remove duplicates by both columns:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['id1', 'id2'])
```

---

Your solution is different - remove duplicates separately first looking by first and then by second column:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['id1'], inplace = False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['id2'], inplace = False)
```

Parameter `inplace = False` is by default in [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), so should be removed:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['id1'])
df = df.drop_duplicates(['id2'])
```

Comment: Thanks - can you take a look at my edited question? this answer worked but it doesnt seem to work in conjunction when I run my other function first that removes all combinations that are equal @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - What is expected output from your data?

Comment: For example in the above sample data in my question -  only the last row would stay - 

I want to remove all rows where the ids are the same combination like row 1 and row 3 ( where the id1 and id 2 are the same combination just switched for the column, then I also want to remove all duplicates in col id1 and and col id2 @jezrael

Comment: I will tag this post as answered as it was and open a new question sorry ! @jerael